# make an array of dictionary in plist swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to create a plist like this...
I am using this code from Objective-C translated to Swift...
unfortunately the array empty remains

What is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
 <plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>

            <key>Uscita_Ore</key>
            <string>18</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>

            <key>Uscita_Ore</key>
            <string>17</string>
        </dict>
</array>
</plist>

var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
            var documentsDirectory:AnyObject = paths[0]
            var path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("orari_marcate.plist")
            var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            var fileExists:Bool = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)
            var lista_marcate : NSMutableDictionary?
            var marcate2 :NSMutableArray?

            if fileExists == false {

                marcate2 = NSMutableArray (capacity: 0) 
            } else  {

                marcate2 = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
            }

            lista_marcate?.setValue("\(campo_Ora_Fine.text)", forKey: "campo_Ora_Fine")
            lista_marcate?.setValue("\(campo_Min_Fine.text)", forKey: "campo_Min_Fine")
            lista_marcate?.setValue("\(fine_Ora)", forKey: "fine_Ora")
            lista_marcate?.setValue("\(fine_Min)", forKey: "fine_Min")


            marcate2?.addObject(lista_marcate!)

            marcate2?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true) 

            println(path)
```

Comment: Didn't you omit anything crucial while pasting your code here? `lista_marcate` is not created at all in this snippet, so the line `marcate2?.addObject(lista_marcate!)` would crash.

Comment: I omitted the lines that are not critical...

Comment: You are right now crash...is strange was fine before!!